# Ethernet way slower than wireless

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

My Ethernet connection is much slower than my wireless connection, I have no idea why. I was under the impression that wired was the way to go.

Ethernet speed test:

[image]

---

Wirleless speed test:

[image]

I pay for 400Mbps down and 40Mbps up.

Comment: Tried a different wire, a brand new one that's short and really close to the router/modem? The plug isn't damaged or dirty is it?

Comment: Try a different cable (Cat5e or better), different ports on switch/router, and if you do have a switch between the PC and router try connecting directly to the router.

Comment: I have this cable @Xen2050

https://www.shopmyexchange.com/patrionics-cat5e-patch-7-ft-cable/5905008

Comment: @FastEthernet I have this one, https://www.shopmyexchange.com/patrionics-cat5e-patch-7-ft-cable/5905008

Comment: What nic chipset do you have in your PC? If it's a realtek that could be your issue. It could also be a cable/cabling issue.

Comment: @davidgo how do I find that out?

Comment: There could be many factors impacting your issue, you should provide more details. Like, length of your cable, it's standard (category 5e or 6).
What is your router?
What is you network card?
What I can see is that your upload seems to be about the same speed - that could indicate some configuration (like QoS) on your router that limits your download. Were you testing on the same server in your speed test?

Comment: Strange that you upload is faster or more or less unchanged when both your ping and your download are smaller or very smaller.